# Align bottom of floated text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to design a table-free input form. I'm gradually making my way through it was I learn new things about CSS. But I can't figure out how to get my smaller validation text to align to the bottom of the field's label text.

```
<div style="width:275px">
    <div style="width:175px">
        <label style="float:left;">Label</label>
        <span style="float:right; font-size:x-small; color:#FF0000;">Required</span>
        <input type="text" style="display:block; clear:both; width:100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This displays the "Label" over the top left of the textbox and "Required" over the top right. But the span containing "Required" is smaller font and it seems to be anchored to the top right corner so the text is aligned higher than the bottom of the "Label" text. How do I make the bottoms align?

Comment: I think it's style="vertical-align: baseline;"

Comment: You would think. But vertical-align has no effect. I suspect because I am using float, it's considering the label and span block level elements so vertical-align doesn't apply.

Comment: Man, there was one that I think had the answer to this yesterday. No idea where it is though. I'll see if I can find it and copy it here.

Comment: If you're okay with fixed numbers, you can do margin-top: 5px or padding-top: 5px or line-height: 24px

Comment: In order to use the `vertical-align property`, the containing element has to have something else in it - like an image - to dictate what constitues top, middle, or bottom. It's clunky and imho completely useless. Here's a longer explanation: http://tinyurl.com/aowys7l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple different ways, but I've found this one to be the most efficient

```
<div style="width:275px">
    <div style="width:175px">
        <div style="position:relative; height: 2em;">
            <label style="position:absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0;">Label</label>
            <span style="position:absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; font-size:x-small; color:#FF0000;">Required</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" style="display:block; clear:both; width:100%" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This will also save you from needing to clear everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add `margin-top:5` to "Required"

Comment: This is a bad idea due to scaleability. For people (like visually impaired) who enlarge their fonts, having a 5px margin at the top will still leave it floating when the main text is enlarged. For the record, I would also avoid using `font-size:x-small` and instead use scaleable units, like `em` or `%`

Comment: I think its a safe solution for this example because its all enclosed in a div to help manage its dimensions.

Comment: The size of the div doesn't matter. to be ADA compliant you need to accomodate font-size overrides. All browsers can set all fonts to be a certain family or size. If your div is a hard size and the font you've set to be 12px is overridden to be 18px, it will break your layout. Bad. These days in general your entire layout should be set in `%` or `em` to accomodate for varient devices and user needs/overrides (including div widths, heights, etc) but at the _very_ least your fonts should be set to be in _relation_ to eachother rather than px sizes or they'll all be the same size when overridden.